# Why do I get duplicates when trying to append csv files

Tags: python, xml, csv, append

I wrote a function `parse_xml` that convert xml to csv. Then I want to convert every files within a folder (100,000 files) and append all into 1 file. My code for that task is

```
result=pd.DataFrame()
os.chdir('/Users/dp/Dropbox/Ratings/SP')

for file in list(glob.glob('*.xml')):
    data = marshal.dumps(file)
    obj = marshal.loads(data)
    parse_xml(obj)
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
    result = pd.concat([result,pd.DataFrame.from_records(df)])
    result.to_csv('output.csv')
```

However the result isn't what I'm looking for. It keeps re-appending all over again with similar files. 90% of the ouput's observations are duplicated.

Could somebody please give me a hint on how to resolve this issue? Thank you so much

Comment: it seems as though you are writing files to the same folder as you are reading and therefore it will continue. what you need to do is create a second folder (just for the XML) and write to this....  and finally loop that folder for the collation.

Comment: I believe you need to add `with open('output.csv', 'a') as csv_file:` then the `for file in ...` indented under that and `result.to_csv(csv_file)`.